# Passing PHP session to external ASP app

Tags: php, asp.net

I have been asked by a client if it was possible to build a PHP site which will pass sessions to an other app located on a different server which uses ASP.

I was wondering if any of you had a prior experience with this ? And if so how problematic can this task be? Is there any resources that you would recommend about that topic ?

Thanks a bunch for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is nothing but an identifier which points to some data on the server.
You can use [session_save_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and friends to manage how these are saved (e.g. store in a database instead of default files used by PHP) and parse/use the data connected to the session from you ASP code.

Comment: Thanks alex, though i think my question wasn't exactly well formulated,  i remade a topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586790/how-to-pass-secure-information-in-between-several-servers-under-different-os-lin. Maybe you ll have some more insight/pointers to share